# In Overlord, were the NPC's personalities merely flavor text in Yggdrasil?

Tags: overlord

It was shown that Shaltear and Aura were created to tease each other. Other characters were created with different personality traits as well. Did the characters' personality traits influence their behavior in Yggdrasil or was it merely flavor text until they were transported to the new world?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Momonga mentions at the start of the first volume that it was just flavor text. Seeing how surprised he was to learn that Albedo was supposed to be a sort of slut because of gap moe, she probably didn't have any dialogue that would indicate this without reading her lore. I'm too lazy to read the novel again and pinpoint the source so I'll leave the answering to someone else tho.